# How to select oldest item from records with overlapping dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with team names, the date the team was created, and the date the team was dissolved:

```
TeamName                                TeamStartDate           TeamEndDate
Business Analysis                       2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2013-06-30 00:00:00.000
Business Systems                        2012-06-18 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
Business Systems and Portfolio          2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
Data Administration/eCommerce/Testing   2012-10-29 00:00:00.000 2013-10-10 00:00:00.000
Data Solutions                          2013-10-11 00:00:00.000 2099-12-31 00:00:00.000
Data Solutions-Reporting                2012-12-31 00:00:00.000 2013-10-10 00:00:00.000
```

Some teams get renamed (as in the case of Business Systems and Portfolio) and I want to be able to select the correct team for a specific date.  For example, if my report is to run for 1st August 2015, I want to see "Business Systems and Portfolio", but if the report is to run for 12th December 2014, I want to see "Business Systems".  I've been trying to figure out how to do this, but can't quite get there.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: I am using SQL server.

Comment: How exactly you know it is the same team? in that data, you could have renamed "Business Analysis"  to "Business Systems"... or renamed it to  "Pie" for all we know. You need to provide an identifier that tells both names actually belong to the same team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is: **Unable to determine; not enough information.**

You could have renamed "Business Analysis" to "Business Systems"... or renamed it to "Pie" for all we know. You need to an identifier that tells both names actually belong to the same team.

If the data would include a team's unique identifier, then the following example would provide the oldest name for a given team:

```
DECLARE @teams TABLE(TeamID INT, TeamName varchar(100), TeamStartDate date, TeamEndDate date)

INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(1, 'Business Analysis                    ','2012-12-31 00:00:00.000','2013-06-30 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(2, 'Business Systems                     ','2012-06-18 00:00:00.000','2015-01-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(2, 'Business Systems and Portfolio       ','2012-12-31 00:00:00.000','2099-12-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(3,'Data Administration/eCommerce/Testing','2012-10-29 00:00:00.000','2013-10-10 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(4,'Data Solutions                       ','2013-10-11 00:00:00.000','2099-12-31 00:00:00.000')
INSERT INTO @teams VALUES(5, 'Data Solutions-Reporting             ','2012-12-31 00:00:00.000','2013-10-10 00:00:00.000')

SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT TeamName, TeamStartDate, TeamEndDate, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TeamID ORDER by TeamID) num
        FROM @teams
        WHERE '2014-12-12 00:00:00' BETWEEN TeamStartDate AND TeamEndDate) a
WHERE  a.num = 1
```

Results:

```
TeamName            TeamStartDate TeamEndDate num
------------------- ------------- ----------- ---
Business Systems    2012-06-18    2015-01-31  1
Data Solutions      2013-10-11    2099-12-31  1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TeamName, TeamStartDate, TeamEndDate
FROM [TableName]
WHERE '2015-08-01 00:00:00' BETWEEN TeamStartDate AND TeamEndDate
```

01/08/2015 is the date you want to search on

Answer (score 0):

If you have a key to identify which descriptions go with a particular team (I called it teamkey) then this would work (in Oracle)...

```
    SELECT *
       FROM TheTable t
       WHERE  TRUNC(TheDate) between TRUNC(t.teamstartdate) AND 
              TRUNC(t.teamenddate)
          AND NOT EXISTS 
           (SELECT * 
               FROM TheTable z 
               WHERE t.teamkey = z.teamkey AND 
                     TRUNC(z.teamenddate) < TRUNC(t.teamenddate) AND
                     TRUNC(z.teamenddate) > TRUNC(TheDate)   )
```

Comment: Alas, I am using MS-SQL.  I forgot to mention that.